# CMAC-AES in Python

Tags: python, encryption

I am trying to implement an integration with this api in a Django app.http://pdn.pearson.com/pearson-learningstudio/apis/authentication/authentication-use-cases/use-case-submit-request-using-oauth2-assertion_x

Almost everything works, except for using their assertion authentication method.  I need to encrypt an assertion string using CMAC-AES, and I have no idea how to do that.

All of their sample code uses built in libraries to the languages, and I cannot find any libraries that will let me do that in Python.  I have been googling around all day, and have found precisely nothing.

Does anybody know where I can get a library which will let me do this?  Or how to work around it

Thanks

-Alex

Comment: Maybe of some help: it seems this package has an implementation of it: http://wiki.yobi.be/wiki/PyCryptoPlus

Comment: Almost two years later and I'm having the same problem...  I don't like Pearson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PyCryptoPlus](http://wiki.yobi.be/wiki/PyCryptoPlus) library implements CMAC-AES. This is an excerpt from the documentation of AES.py:

```
 CMAC EXAMPLE:
-------------
NIST publication 800-38B: http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38B/Updated_CMAC_Examples.pdf

>>> key = '2b7e151628aed2a6abf7158809cf4f3c'.decode('hex')
>>> plaintext = '6bc1bee22e409f96e93d7e117393172a'.decode('hex')
>>> cipher = AES.new(key,AES.MODE_CMAC)
>>> cipher.encrypt(plaintext).encode('hex')
'070a16b46b4d4144f79bdd9dd04a287c'
```

Code: http://repo.or.cz/w/python-cryptoplus.git/tree/HEAD

Comment: I tried this out.  Got it set up, but every time I add it to the codebase, our site completely crashes.  I can't figure out why, and I am apprehensive about a library that has problems like that right off the bat.  Beggars can't be choosers though... :(

Comment: It turns out there is a bug in the latest version of PyCryptoPlus.  1 missing space.  I forked it here https://github.com/alexhughson/PyCryptoPlus and fixed it.

Comment: @AlexH Were you using `requests` + `requests-oauthlib` to make your requests to Pearson? If so, how did you shim PyCryptoPlus into OAuthLib?

Answer (score 2):

The current alpha version of [PyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) includes CMAC as the module [`Crypto.Hash.CMAC`](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/master/lib/Crypto/Hash/CMAC.py).

For example:

```
from Crypto.Hash import CMAC
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

secret = b'Sixteen byte key'
cobj = CMAC.new(secret, ciphermod=AES)
cobj.update(b'Hello')
print cobj.hexdigest()
```

Comment: I've had problems installing the alpha on my local machine (OSX 10.11).  It installed just fine on my Debian server... Did you have any issues getting this working?

Comment: There seems to be an issue building it on yosemite right now: https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/issues/141